# What are these two equations related to Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution called?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, terminology, notation, chemical-potential

I have come across these two equations on Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution:

[image: Equation 1]

and

[image: Equation 2]

May I please know what the equations are called so I can read up more about them?

Comment: Welcome to physics.stackexchange. Please use mathjax for formulas. :)

Comment: And if you type in "Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution" into some search engine and go to Wikipedia, you'll find the first equation, and a link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_statistics. So I think you should be more specific about what your problem is, or do some research first yourself.

Comment: Sorry about using images, I will try and fix it.

About the names, I had looked at Wikipedia but I still do not know what the name of the formulas are. For example, some online sources call the formula under Maxwell Boltzmann statistics as Maxwell Boltzmann Distributive Law, so I am confused.

Would it be accurate to call the first formula "Maxwell-Boltzmann Distribution Law", and the second "Maxwell-Boltzmann Statistics Law" instead? 

Thank you!

Comment: Both are part of Maxwell–Boltzmann statistics. The first is "Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution for the velocity of particles in a gas" and the second is the "Boltzmann factor".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first formula is indeed the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution, a probability distribution for velocities in an ideal gas. Cf. Wikipedia.

The second one is not even a probability distribution in the given form because it is lacking a normalization factor. This is a formula used in Maxwell-Boltzmann statistics (and physicists like to call $\text{e}^{-\frac{E}{k_B T}}$ for some energy $E$ a "Boltzmann factor").

So to speak, Maxwell-Boltzmann statistics (and thus, in part, the second formula) is a general tool in statistical mechanics, while the first formula is a result for a specific physical system.